# How to display a RichTextBox in an ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, richtextbox, itemscontrol

I'm spinning nowhere on this. I am creating a RichTextBox in the ViewModel.

I want to display this RichTextBox on a Canvas using a basic ItemsControl. All I'm getting is an empty square in the top left of the canvas. I would like to position the top-left corner of the RichTextBox at a specific position on the Canvas--and actually see the contents of it!

XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Paragraphs}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="Transparent"
                    Width="{x:Static h:Constants.widthCanvas}" 
                    Height="{x:Static h:Constants.heightCanvas}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ink:RichTextBoxViewModel}">
            <RichTextBox />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

How is this done?  Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: I checked it works, but I am concerneg that you did not mean to have this. Code above will display as many RichTextBoxes as many items your ItemsSource containts, is that what you wish?

Comment: @Maximus Yes. However, I am not able to visualize the flowdocument, but rather get an empty (small) square to the top left of the canvas.  I am guessing, but every solution I've found requires reinventing the RichtextBox as a UserControl. It seems like a lot of work to simply view the flowdocument.

Comment: Apparently your ItemsSource Paragraphs contains only one element.